# Getting narrator to read accessibility description using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make my application more accessible by adding information into the accessible name and accessible description properties on my controls. However narrator is only reading out the accessible name. Is there a way I can get it to also read out the accessible description? I've looked through the settings in narrator and haven't found anything. I've tried adding `ControlName.AccessibleRole = AccessibleRole.Application` which seems to do the trick when using JAWS, however doesn't resolve my issue when using narrator.

Comment: Which control class are you trying the AccessibleDescription?

Comment: @AjithNair I'm just trying to give a button an AccessibleDescription